# C# List of splitted strings

Tags: c#, string, list, for-loop, split

I have the following problem.
I have these strings with whitespace between them.

```
"+name:string"            "+age:int"
```

I split them with this code:

```
List<string> stringValueList = new List<string>();
stringValueList = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(stringValue, @"\s{2,}").ToList<string>();
```

now the elements of List looks like this

```
"+name:string"
"+age:int"
```

Now I want to split these strings and create Objects.
This looks like this:

```
// Storing the created objects in a List of objects
List<myObject> objectList = new List<myObject>();
for(i = 1; i < stringValueList.Count ; i+=2)
{
   myObject object = new myObject();

   object.modifier = '+';
   object.name = stringValueList[i-1].Trim('+');   // out of the example the object.name should be "name"
   object.type = stringValueList[i];   // out of the example the object.type value should "string"

   objectList.Add(object);
}
```

At the end I should get two objects with these values:

```
List<myObject> objectList{ myObject object1{modifier = '+' , name ="name" , type="string"}, myObject object2{modifier='+', name="age" type="int"}}
```

But my result looks like this:

```
List<myObject> objectList {myObject object1 {modifier='+', name="name:string" type="+age:int"}}
```

So instead of getting 2 Objects, I am getting 1 Object. It puts both strings into the elements of the first object.

Can anyone help me out? I guess my problem is in the for loop because **i-1** value is the first string in the List and **i** is the second string but I cant change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess my problem is in the for loop because i-1 value is the first string in the List and i is the second string but I cant change this.

I don't know why you do `i += 2`, because apparently you want to split each string in two again. So just *have* to change that.

Use `foreach()`, and inside your loop, split your string again:

```
foreach (var stringValue in stringValueList)
{
    myObject object = new myObject();

    var kvp = stringValue.Split(':');

    object.modifier = '+';
    object.name = kvp[0].Trim('+');
    object.type = kvp[1];

    objectList.Add(object);
}
```

Of course this code assumes your inputs are always valid; you'd have to add some boundary checks to make it more robust.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could expand your `Regex` formula to do the whole thing in one go.

For example, with [(?<=")[+](.*?):(.*?)(?=")](https://regex101.com/r/6NOpl1/1), all you'd have to do is assign the matched group values.

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(stringValue, "(?<=\")[+](.*?):(.*?)(?=\")"))
{
    myObject obj = new myObject
    {
        modifier = '+',
        name = m.Groups[1].Value,
        type = m.Groups[2].Value
    };
    objectList.Add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting to see how others approach a problem. I would have done something like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public char Modifier { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<MyObject> Parse(string str)
    {
        return str
        .Split(' ')
        .Where(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) == false)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(i =>
        {
            var sections = i.Remove(0, 1).Split(':');
            return new MyObject()
            {
                Modifier = i[0],
                Name = sections[0],
                Type = sections[1]
            };
        });
    }
}
```